# Push View Controller from External Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two classes; `MasterView` which is a `UIViewController` that displays my TableView and `MyClass` which acts as the delegate and datasource for the TableView for various reasons. I need to push a view controller (`DetailView`) when a cell is selected. How can I push the view from MyClass? This is all I really have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (!detailViewController) {
    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
}

//Somehow push detailViewController
}
```

Comment: How an where do you create the instance of MyClass? Also, is it a subclass of NSObject?

Comment: I am calling the method in MyClass. Set it is a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: The question I asked was how and where do you create your instance of MyClass? Does MasterView do that? You need to get a reference to the navigation controller somehow, so I'm trying to figure out how your two classes are connected to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this. I assume you already have your `Masterview` embedded in a `UINavigationController` right?

You can access it by passing a reference to your `Masteriew` and then use:

```
[masterView.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

If your `Masterview` is somehow related to your App's Delegate and you want to access it, you could use the following line too:

```
MainClass *appDelegate = (MainClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: I actually tried your first suggestion initially but it failed. Could you please explain the second part in more detail?

Comment: The first suggestion is based on your masterview being embedded into a navigation controller. If you're using Storyboards you could just select the MasterViewController then select "Editor" -> "Embed In" -> "NavigationController" from the Menubar. From now on my first solution should work.

The second tipp may help you in accessing your masterview. This was just in case you do now have a direct reference to you mv and you AppDelegate has, you could access it like this: appDelegate.masterview.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I was confused on what `MainClass` was. I Just replaced it with `AppDelegate` then called `appDelegate.navigation` controller.

Comment: Happy it worked! If it's a "real" project and not just a test you're doing there, try keeping the Model-View-Controller pattern in mind. It's a pain in the back if you use your AppDelegate as one ViewController. Trust me, I've been there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a property on the UITableViewDelegate as UINavigationController, and simply set it when creating the tableViewDelegate.  Seem ok?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a navigation controller, just use this method:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated];
```